# what is difference between Serilog.Sinks.File and Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

what is difference between Serilog.Sinks.File and Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File packages in asp.net core?

When I tried to implement logging in asp.net core project with Serilog I found a quick example [here](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/10/aspnet-core-file-logger/) which used Serilog.Sinks.File.

When I tried to implement the same in my project,the logger factory didnt have the extension AddFile().

But when I added another extension Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File I got the extension.

Are both extensions needed? or just Logging.File extension is enough?

What is the basic difference Sinks.File and Logging.File ?

Answer (score 3):

In the link you provided, the example **explicitly use** `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File`.

It is this extension that provide the `AddFile` method to `ILoggerFactory` (via Extension Methods mecanisms in DotNet) :

[Extension of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.IloggerFactory](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file/blob/305d5033bcdaffe3b1d1d3909a11bdbb250e9454/src/Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File/Microsoft/Extensions/Logging/FileLoggerExtensions.cs#L28)

A quick look at the Nuget [package definition](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File) of `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File` indicates that it has a **dependency** on 
`Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile`.
The latter extension itself has a dependency on `Serilog.Sinks.File`.

So, `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File` extends `ILoggerFactory`, providing the `AddFile()` method. That method uses the `RollingFile` class ([as seen in the source code](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file/blob/305d5033bcdaffe3b1d1d3909a11bdbb250e9454/src/Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File/Microsoft/Extensions/Logging/FileLoggerExtensions.cs#L129)).